# Replace NAs with n most frequent values

Tags: r, vector, replace, na

Here are 2 dummy vectors:

```
set.seed(10)
vec1 <- c(1,1,5,1,2,5,1,7,9,1,3,1,1,2 ,2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1,1,1,1,1,1,2,5,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,1,1,2,1,7,1,7,2,1,1,1)
vec <- c(1,1,5,1,2,5,1,7,9,1,3,1,1,2 ,2, 1, 2, 1, 3, 1,1,1,1,1,1,2,5,1,NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)
```

I would like to replace missing values in vec with 4 most frequent values in vec1. I would like to sort these values randomly (insert them instead of NAs in random order, not - for instance - from the greatest to lowest etc.).

I wrote a following code:

```
# take 4 most frequent values
mfv <- as.numeric(names(sort(table(vec1),decreasing=TRUE)[1:4]))

# replace
result <- lapply(vec, function(n) replace(n, is.na(n), as.integer(mfv)))
```

The replace part does not working. How should it be done? I would like to mention, that IRL data may contain the amount of NAs divisible by the amount of selected mfvs or not - the real dataset is large and diverse.

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: How about `vec[is.na(vec)]<-sample(mfv,sum(is.na(vec)),T)`?

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted. And in another scenario, if I would have to apply this function through a list - how would that be?

Comment: Wrap the functionality into a function and use `lapply` or `sapply` to run through the list and do the replacement.

Comment: I did this: result_split <- lapply(lista, function(n) replace(n, is.na(n), sample(mfv,sum(is.na(n)),T))), where "lista" is my list of vecs.